# How to override existing Permission model __str__ method() in django?

Tags: python, django

By default Permission model **str** method returns objects as '%s | %s' % (self.content_type, self.name).I want to display only self.name.Is there any way to do this?
I tried this but it is not working.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
class Permission(Permission):
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

Comment: your imported class name is equal to custom class. have you tried changing that.

Comment: @sriramkumar: I think this is a (failed) attempt to do "monkey patching": https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/monkey-patching-in-python-dynamic-behavior/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your thing doesn't work because your custom `Permission` class is not related to the `Permission` class from `django.contrib.auth.models`, even if it does inherit from it. Try to set the `Permission.__str__` to your function

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
def permission_string_method(self):
    return '%s' % (self.name)
Permission.__str__ = permission_string_method
```

Or even better, us `lambda`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

Permission.__str__ = lambda self: '%s' % (self.name)
```

Comment: In witch file should someone put this?

Comment: Wherever you want to override the class...

Comment: I mean so it would affect the whole project and not in an specific place, if I override it inside of a function I only call in a view, for example, it'll only change inside the view scope, right?

Comment: Add it in the global sccope, then. In `views.py`, for example.